# draw a rectangle using points using mid points of opposite sides

Tags: python, opencv

It's quite common to draw a rectangle using the upper_left and the bottom_right but I only have the midpoints of the width side.
[image: Rectangle]

This looks doable since it's perfectly aligned to the x axis but I'm not sure how to achieve when these two coordinate are at an angle.

I tried to get the upper_left and bottom_right coordinates but calculating them at an angle is posing to be a challenge
[image: Rectangle-slanted]

Comment: It's just trigonometry.  The angle of tilt from vertical is arctan(deltax/deltay), but remember, even if you find upper left and lower right, you can't just draw a rectangle.  You'll have to draw individual lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres my approach on getting the four corners:

```
def get_corners(point1,point2,width):
    # width /= 2
    m1 = (point1[1]-point2[1])/(point1[0]-point2[0])
    m2 = -1/m1
    cor_x = math.sqrt((width/2)**2 / (m2**2 + 1))
    cor_y = math.sqrt((width/2)**2 / (m2**-2 + 1))
    if m2 >= 0:
        corner1 = (point1[0] + cor_x, point1[1] + cor_y)
        corner2 = (point1[0] - cor_x, point1[1] - cor_y)
        corner3 = (point2[0] + cor_x, point2[1] + cor_y)
        corner4 = (point2[0] - cor_x, point2[1] - cor_y)
    else:
        corner1 = (point1[0] - cor_x, point1[1] + cor_y)
        corner2 = (point1[0] + cor_x, point1[1] - cor_y)
        corner3 = (point2[0] - cor_x, point2[1] + cor_y)
        corner4 = (point2[0] + cor_x, point2[1] - cor_y)
    return corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4

print(get_corners((4,8),(-4,-8),math.sqrt(80)))
```

results:

```
((0.0, 10.0), (8.0, 6.0), (-8.0, -6.0), (0.0, -10.0))
```

which corresponds to:
[rectangle used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoWPW.png)
After that just plot all the lines as usual based on your upper_left/ bottom_right method

Comment: @PrudviKamtam this is my first accepted answer, thank you so much. However, I found a small mistake of mine at line two, `width /= 2`, already edited it hope it didn't cause much trouble

Comment: yeah that's alright, I commented it as well. Kudos! :D